# What is equivalent to WakeOnLan software in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

Wake On Lan is very useful GUI based software in Windows. Is there any equivalent for Ubuntu available/

Comment: What does wake on lan do?

Answer (score 1):

An app is already there -

gWakeOnLan

[image: Install via the software center]

As recommened in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan